# Vertical viewport error. Can't fix with even Shrink Wrap or Expanded

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This is my code

```
 ListView.builder(
          itemCount: customerList.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: Expanded(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(customerList[index].customerName),
                  subtitle: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(customerList[index].customerID),
                      Text(customerList[index].customerAddress),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

I have Used Shrink Wrap and Scroll direction and I have tried Getting Rid of the expanded widget but i am still getting this error

here is debug console

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded width.
Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a vertical shrinkwrapping viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand.
```

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#90e43 relayoutBoundary=up23 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Container and Expanded Widget your code is working well.

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: customerList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(customerList[index].customerName),
              subtitle: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(customerList[index].customerID),
                  Text(customerList[index].customerAddress),
                ],
              ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Result: [image]

Answer (score 0):

First, Expanded Widget has a wrong parent.

**Expanded widget can be a child of only Column, Row or Flex.**

Second, You can't expand within a `ListView`.

in simple words:

**`ListView` offers infinity of space while `Expanded` allocates all of the available space**, So they are working in opposite goals.

---

I think your goal is to make sure the `ListTile` fills the entire `Container`, if so.

by default it will fill the container, but you need to set intrinsic dimensions at least a height for the `Container`, as you know how the container works.

**`Container` fills the available space also, which must be prevented as long as it exists within a `ListView`**

So, to fix your code:

- Remove `Expanded` Widget.
- Set an Intrinsic height for the `Container` which wraps the
  `ListTile`, or remove it.

Hope it helps you.